# How does Delphi's _trunc function work and how can I reprogram it?

Tags: delphi

I would like to know how the `_trunc` function in Delphi (32-bit) works.
I know about the signed and unsigned flag and the shift operations to accomplish this kind of operation but I don't know and understand the use of it yet.
So how does the `_trunc` function work and how could I redeclare/reprogram it?
I'm referring to this type: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Trunc

Comment: Why do you want to redeclare/reprogram it? Can't you just call it? Are you aware that it uses a non-standard calling convention? And please don't link to Delphi basics. Link to the real docs: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Trunc

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Of course I could call it, though I would like to know how it works. A good way to do so would be to reprogram the same function and see it line for line.

Comment: If you are intent on doing something so silly, you have the RTL source code available. Look at it and see how they do it, and then do some research to see what each of the FPU instructions that are used accomplish. You'll find those instructions at Intel.

Comment: @KenWhite I can't find the trunc function in the RTL cause it seems to be native within the compiler.

Comment: In Delphi 2007, `procedure _TRUNC;`'s implementation is at line #4201 in `System.pas`.

Comment: You can also define a record with [`operator overloading`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)) and declare a class operator Trunc() that behaves as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Trunc` function is an [intrinsic](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines). And it's quite an interesting one because it uses a non-standard calling convention.

The x86 implementation of it can be found in the `System` unit and looks like this:

```
procedure _Trunc;
asm
        { ->    FST(0)  Extended argument       }
        { <-    EDX:EAX Result                  }

        SUB     ESP,12
        FNSTCW  [ESP].Word          // save
        FNSTCW  [ESP+2].Word        // scratch
        FWAIT
        OR      [ESP+2].Word, $0F00  // trunc toward zero, full precision
        FLDCW   [ESP+2].Word
        FISTP   qword ptr [ESP+4]
        FWAIT
        FLDCW   [ESP].Word
        POP     ECX
        POP     EAX
        POP     EDX
end;
```

Although it is declared as a procedure with no parameters, it receives its input parameter in `ST(0)` and returns the result in `EDX:EAX` as the comments explain.

I'm not a big fan of that implementation and would write it like this:

```
procedure _Trunc;
const
  CW: Word=$1F3F; // trunc toward zero, full precision, mask all exceptions
var
  SaveCW: Word;
  Result: record
    Lo, Hi: Integer;
  end;
asm
  { ->    FST(0)  Extended argument       }
  { <-    EDX:EAX Result                  }
  FSTCW   SaveCW   // save
  FLDCW   CW
  FISTP   Result
  FLDCW   SaveCW   // restore
  FWAIT            // raise any exceptions
  MOV     EAX, Result.Lo
  MOV     EDX, Result.Hi
end;
```

Comment: I thought it would be more like shifting bits to achieve the goal. But I know understand the Delphi Intrinsic Routines. Thank you for clearing that up.